# Less than two variables

Tags: java

I have tried to search as much as I can but it's kinda hard when you are a beginner. Anyway im trying to learn Java and im stuck on a question that says "var1 can be bigger than var2 or var3 but not both. And im supposed to answer with a Boolean value.

```
e = var1 > var2 || var1 > var3 && var1 < var2 + var3;
```

If I do this I end up with it just doing a total sum of var2 and var3. How do I do like

```
var1 < var2 AND var3;
```

Comment: You need to add some parentheses.

Comment: Presumably "not both" here doesn't mean "not more than the sum"

Comment: is the return val a `Boolean` (instance of the class) or a `boolean` (primative datatype)?

Comment: Perhaps *"can be bigger"* should really be *"must be bigger"*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [exclusive-OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operator:

```
(var1 > var2) ^ (var1 > var3)
```

`A ^ B` is `true` if and only if either `A` or `B` (but not both) are `true`:

```
A  B  A^B
---------
0  0   0
0  1   1
1  0   1
1  1   0
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. Weird how I didn't read anywhere about it.

Comment: @user2599508 It's not one of the most common operators.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Nothing in the question says that `var1` _has_ to be bigger than `var2` or `var3`.

Comment: @Keppil That's what I stated in my own answer, but if it's ok with the OP, he just misasked his question...

Comment: @arshajii: That doesn't change the fact that this doesn't answer the question correctly in its current form.

Comment: @Keppil Then the question should be edited, since this is clearly the answer the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If `var1` "can" be bigger than `var2`, and "can" be bigger than `var3`, but not both, the answer is pretty simple.

```
boolean response = !(var1>var2 && var1>var3)
boolean response = (var1<=var2 || var1<=var3)
```

Comment: @afsantos thanks for the edit, I'm not used to SO's formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Determine what the bigger one of var2 and var3 is and check is var1 is bigger than that? If that returns true you already know it's bigger than both. (e: that's one way at least, might not be the best.)

Answer (score 0):

XOR is not out of the box in java
you should test both case
if((x1>x2 && x1<xx3)||(x1<x2 && x1>x3))

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (var1 > var2 ||var1 > var3 && !(var1 < (var2 + var3) )){
   Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can check like this:

```
e = (var1 > var2 ) || (var1 > var3) && (var1 < var2) + var3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to consider associativity of operators (usually left to right in Java) as well as operator precedence (multiplication before addition and so on)

var1 can be bigger than var2 or var3 but not both

`(var1 > var2 || var1 > var3) && !(var1 > var2 && var1 > var3)`

Or you can use exclusive or operator as suggested in one of the other answers which requires the least code.